# JMSDeliveryMode and Message Persistence

Tags: ibm-mq

This is a question in continuation of the discussion in [WebSphere MQ and Atomikos - Messages Lost on process termination](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12461572/910492)

Does the JMSDeliveryMode mentioned in [JMS fields and properties with corresponding MQMD fields](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/uj25450_.htm) determine if the MQ Message is persistent or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, so long as the message is put there using IBM's JMS classes.  The classes will translate the `JMSDeliveryMode` value into one of the WebSphere MQ persistence values.

A C program might try to set or change the message properties so that they differ from the message header and I'm not sure whether the WMQ API will enforce the consistency in that case or not.

But, to reiterate the first part, the answer is yes.  The page linked describes how the JMS properties map onto the native WMQ headers and `JMSDeliveryMode` does indeed map to `MQMD.Persistence`.

I notice your link to the V6.0 Infocenter.  Hopefully you are not still using WMQ V6.0 since it goes End of Service in a few days.  The current Infocenter topic for the same information is [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm25430_.htm) and you will find it is reorganized and clarifies some of the points.  I highly recommend moving to at least a V7.1 client and QMgr, preferably V7.5 - and of course, the corresponding Infocenter.

**UPDATE:**
Responding to the comments, the order of precedence is as follows:

1. If persistence is set explicitly in the managed object object definition as described [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm41630_.htm), then it takes precedence.
2. If the managed object is set to `PERSISTENCE=APP` (the default) then the application's setting takes precedence.
3. If neither the managed object nor the app explicitly set persistence, then the default is to look at the setting on the queue and use that.

Note that if the queue where the message is first put happens to be a transmission queue, persistence is determined at that point and travels with the message wherever it lands, even if the remote target queue is set to `DEFPSIST(NO)`.

If you look closely at the page linked in the first bullet, you will notice a possible persistence value of HIGH.  The description of that value seems to have fallen out of the book (I'll report that) but it is on [this page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm25200_.htm). This is a "best effort" delivery mode of JMS that falls between WMQ's persistent and non-peristent modes.  Since there is no native equivalent, WMQ implements this by using non-persistent messages on a queue that is marked for recovery.  When the QMgr starts up, any non-persistent messages on the queue will be saved, assuming the shutdown and startup were normal and that the queue file is not damaged.  Even on a QMgr with linear logging, these messages are not logged for media recovery so there is only one copy of them.  So most of the time, these messages survive a restart but if there is any condition which the QMgr can resolve by deleting them it will.

Note the warning on the page that says all queues a message passes through must be set to `NPMCLASS(HIGH)` in order for this to work. I'm not sure what happens to the messages if they land on a queue with `NPMSPEED(NORMAL)` on the way through the network but you should probably treat them as non-persistent.

Comment: Thank you Rob. As for the version, no, we use v7.1. We will move into v7.5 soon :)

Comment: Is this the default value for JMSDeliveryMode? The value is not set by the client who is sending the message. So even if the queue DEFPSIST is No, the messages will survive a QMgr restart?

Comment: See updated answer.  Thanks for the vote! Getting close to that 10k mark. :-)